# How to make js in my website more efficient?

Tags: javascript, css, performance

So what I am trying to do,  is I am changing the background of a div, using js. The code is:

```
let counter = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  counter ++;
  if(counter == 3) counter = 0;
  switch (counter) {
    case 0 : {
      background1.style.zIndex = "-1";
      background2.style.zIndex = "-2";
      background3.style.zIndex = "-2";

      background1.style.opacity = "1";
      background2.style.opacity = "0";
      background3.style.opacity = "0";
      break;
    }

    case 1 : {
      background2.style.zIndex = "-1";
      background1.style.zIndex = "-2";
      background3.style.zIndex = "-2";

      background2.style.opacity = "1";
      background3.style.opacity = "0";
      background1.style.opacity = "0";
      break;
    }

    case 2 : {
      background3.style.zIndex = "-1";
      background1.style.zIndex = "-2";
      background2.style.zIndex = "-2";

      background3.style.opacity = "1";
      background1.style.opacity = "0";
      background2.style.opacity = "0";
      break;
    }
  }
}, 25000);
```

The main takeaway from this being, I'm running a function in js, every 25 seconds.

Now let's say the 25 seconds is about to be over. And I click on a 'button', which Idk, runs some animation and stuff, then ofc, js being single-threaded, will queue the tasks, and it just looks a bit laggy, as if the 'button' isn't working.

It's not that much of a bad user experience, because the background changing function doesn't do much of a heavy task. So should I ignore it, and hope the user will ignore it too, or what would you do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript's `setInterval` function is asynchronous, so it not blocks the main flow when it in "waiting" state. You click a button to do some animation or somthing else may cause the laggy you said above, I think you can use achieve a smother animation by using [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) as it can get up to 60fps if the processor isn't very busy.
Here is an example code sinippet may help:

```
function update() {
  let elapsedTime = Date.now() - startedAt

  // playback is a value between 0 and 1
  // being 0 the start of the animation and 1 its end
  let playback = elapsedTime / duration

  updateTarget(playback)
  
  if (playback > 0 && playback < 1) {
    // Queue the next frame
    requestAnimationFrame(update)
  } else {
    // Wait for a while and restart the animation
    setTimeout(start, duration/10)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd get better performance by not doing this through Javascript at all but purely in CSS, using an animation. That way the system can use hardware (GPU) where possible and you aren't cluttering up your JS.

Here's a simple example, obviously you want to put in your own images and if the background is for some element other than the body change the CSS to that.

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  animation-name: change;
  animation-duration: 75s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes change {
  0% {
    background: red;
  }
  0.01% {
    background: green;
    }
  33% {
    background: green;
    }
  33.01% {
    background: blue;
    }
  66% {
    background: blue;
    }
  66.01% {
    background: red;
    }
  99.99% {
    background: red;
    }
}
```